# Creating list from retrlines in Python

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

How exactly would you create a list of the entries in an FTP directory?

This is my code so far:

```
import ftplib

files = []

my_ftp = ftplib.FTP(HOST)
my_ftp.login(USERNAME,PASSWORD)

line = my_ftp.retrlines("NLST",files.append(line))
my_ftp.quit()
```

The error says that the variable line is being used before it is defined.

Answer (score 10):

You probably just want to use `nlst`:

```
>>> my_ftp.nlst()
['pub', 'etc', 'ports']
```

Answer (score 5):

A little change to the callback argument and the following should work

```
line = my_ftp.retrlines("NLST",files.append)
```

Comment: Documentation says `retrlines` will call `print_line` if you don't specify `callback`.  That won't work.

Comment: Ahh, `files.append` is even better than `lambda`.  Why didn't I think of that?  :-)

Comment: This is probably not worth doing with `NLST`, because as zigg's answer points out, just `.nlst()` returns a list. This is still worth doing if you want to `.retrlines('LIST -t')` or something, though.