# Get ftp.retrlines to print a file's content to a string

Tags: python, lambda

I want to get the contents of a file with ftplib and store it in a string variable in python. My first attempt is below. I guess lambdas can't contain assignment -- maybe because a lambda is a function + variables that should be self contained (?).

```
contents = ""
ftp.retrlines("RETR " + filename, lambda s: contents=s) #lambda cannot contain assignment
```

Anyway, do I need to capture output to stdout or is there an easier way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969247/creating-list-from-retrlines-in-python I think answers your question with regards to implementation I think the lambda does not work because it is not a callback but not smart enough to be sure

Answer (score 1):

```
outStr = StringIO.StringIO() # Use a string like a file.
ftp.retrlines('RETR ' + fileToGet, outStr.write)
print outStr.getvalue()
outStr.close()
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this fails because [python does not allow statements inside lambdas, only pure expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282042).

Secondly, even if you did this as a function, i,e.:

```
contents = ""
def assign(s):
    contents=s
ftp.retrlines("RETR " + filename, assign )
```

it would fail, because by running `contents=s` you are just creating a *local variable*, not referencing the (global) variable `contents`.

You could further correct it as such:

```
contents = ""
def assign(s):
    global contents
    contents=s
ftp.retrlines("RETR " + filename, assign )
```

But this (using globals) is generally considered a bad practice. Instead, you should probably rethink your callback to *actually do **everything** you need to do with the data*. This is not always easy; you may want to keep [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) in a handy place in your programming belt.