# Python ftplib: How to store results of `FTP.retrlines` in a list?

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I'd like to retrieve files' name of a directory and I use the method `ftplib.retrlines('NLST' + path)`.

It prints all files' names in the directory `path`. But I want to store those files' names in a container, e.g., a list, instead of printing them in the console. How to do that ?

Answer (score 12):

The second (optional) argument to the [`FTP.retrlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrlines) is a `callback`.

```
FTP.retrlines(command[, callback])
```

You can use it like:

```
lines = []
sess.retrlines('NLST ' + path, lines.append)
```

See also [Creating list from retrlines in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9969247/850848).

Answer (score 9):

You can use FTP.nlst() method. It returns the file names as a list.

```
>>> FTP.nlst('path')
['x','y','z']
```

Comment: This does not work in python 3.8

Comment: It does work. Could it be that your FTP server does not support it?
https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.nlst